# In search of a word to describe "being struck by" using active voice

Tags: word-choice

I'm in search of a word that describes the sensation of being struck by something, for example strong wind, but using active voice and having the connotation be that it was pleasurable. Let's say for example: "Ich habe das Fenster geöffnet und den Wind _______". I've already thought of "gespürt", but I felt that it was too weak and a bit too passive, and also "entgegengenommen" in the sense of "embraced", but I don't think that "entgegennehmen" can actually be used in a figurative sense like that.

If anyone has any suggestions, I'd be very thankful to hear them!

Edit: I guess a nice English translation would be "I opened the window and embraced the wind". However, reading all the answers, I kind of came to the conclusion that all variants that aren't passive voice are not that idiomatic, so I think I just have to work with the passive. Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: "entgegengenommen" doesn't mean embraced. It is mainly used if you receive something (mail, packet)

Comment: Can you write the sentence you want in English? I don't understand exactly what you're looking for. Because English *"being struck by"* also is passive voice.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use the person as the agent in this scenario, hence you'll hardly find an active variant. For "spüren", there's still a bit of transitivity involved. But something "stronger" shifts the agency to the wind.  Just like you won't find an active equivalent of "being hit" with opposite direction.

Answer (score 1):

"Ich habe das Fenster geöffnet und den Wind _______"

> genossen
>
> wahrgenommen
>
> empfangen
>
> empfunden

Alternative sentences

> Ich habe das Fenster geöffnet und im Wind gebadet.
>
> Ich habe das Fenster geöffnet und mich am Wind erfreut.
>
> Ich habe das Fenster geöffnet und fand Gefallen am Wind.

Answer (score 1):

(deu) Beide bisherigen Antworten klingen sehr gestelzt - grad mal "am Wind erfreut" ist mit Ach und Krach normal. Warum nicht einfach "Der Wind hat mich gepackt" oder "die Kraft des Windes gespürt"? Im positiven Sinne wirst Du eigentlich "vom Wind begrüßt" (aber das sagt keiner, es wirkt sarkastisch), im negativen Sinne wirst Du "vom Wind erschlagen."

Versuch auf das Wort "Rückenwind" hinzuarbeiten, denn dies ist immer positiv besetzt. Man kann ihn sowohl auf z.B. dem Fahrrad erfahren, als auch als Fußgänger/Wanderer.

---

(eng) Both answers so far sound quite overblown - only "am Wind erfreut" is barely normal. Why not "Der Wind hat mich gepackt" or "die Kraft des Windes gespürt"? When pleased you'd be "vom Wind begrüßt" (but nobody talks this way, hence implying sarcasm), when bothered you'd be "vom Wind erschlagen".

Try to aim at using "Rückenwind" which has always a positive meaning, i.e. the bicycle rider or the pedestrian/hiker.

Answer (score -2):

Beim Segeln dreht man das Segel in den Wind, aber wenn Du Dich nicht vor dem Fenster auch drehst, wirst Du es schlecht adaptieren können.

> Ich habe den Wind in mich fahren lassen.

wäre das beste, das mir bisher eingefallen ist, eventuell auch

> Ich habe den Wind in mich blasen gelassen.

Comment: Wirkt für mich unfreiwilig komisch, ich muss dabei an den Wind denken, der aus einem heraus fährt..